# Python web scraping a table with filters

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am having difficulty extracting text when web-scraping a table, and I think the filters on the page are to blame. I have tried isolating all the "tr" and "th" elements, but cannot seem to get the underlying text into Python. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page_link ='https://www.ersteliga.hu/stats#/players/1945/regular/points'

page = requests.get(page_link)
html = page.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

my_table = soup.find_all('table', class_= "IHD-TABLE")
columns = my_table.find('th')
```

I expect the output to contain the text values seen online, but I seem to get output that looks different than the HTML on the web page.

Comment: That table is dynamically generated with Angular. You'd need to use something that can parse Javascript to get those values, for example Selenium.

Comment: Your table is filled asynchronous, when you download the page the table is empty. Check the js ajax calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data comes dynamically from another xhr request the page makes you can find in the network tab. It returns json.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'referer': 'https://www.ersteliga.hu/stats',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
}
data = {'championshipId': '1945', 'division': 'Alapszakasz','type': 'playerStatsChampionShipPeriod'}
r = requests.post('https://www.ersteliga.hu/ajax/CallWS', headers = headers, data=data).json()
df = pd.DataFrame([i for i in r['d']], columns = list(r['d'][0].keys()))
print(df)
```

Sort on `point` column desc to get same order as on page

```
print(df.sort_values(['point'], ascending=[False]))
```

Comment: For the "data" variable, how did you find the field names (e.g. "type") and their possible values so I can look up other data? Thank you again!

Comment: I inspected to web traffic in dev tools F12 when refreshing the page with F5. If you visit my profile page there are some links that show you how to use this to find dynamic content.